# How to keep text WITHIN div's HTML/Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

So my text is "falling" out of my page at certain sizes, how do I stop this?

I have Googled and tried many things to no avail.

If you check out my screenshot u can see what I mean, and the code that is the victim of this is below as well.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="container">
<div class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" >CRN</th>
      <th scope="col">Subject</th>
      <th scope="col">Course</th>
      <th scope="col">Credits</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Days</th>
      <th scope="col">Times</th>
      <th scope="col">Instructor</th>
      <th scope="col">Attribute</th>
      <th scope="col">Professor Difficulty</th>
      <th scope="col">Professor Rating</th>
      <th scope="col">Would Take Again</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for row in all_data %}
    <tr>
      <th><a href="https://selfserveprod.yu.edu/pls/banprd/bwckschd.p_disp_listcrse?term_in=202109&subj_in={{row['subj']}}&crse_in={{row['crse']}}&crn_in={{row['crn']}}" target="_blank" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Click to get register for this CRN on the YU Banner Site.">{{row['crn']}}</a></th>
      <td><strong>{{row['subj']}}</strong></td>
      <td >{{row['crse']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['cred']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['title']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['days']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['time']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['instr']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['Attr']}}</td>
      <td data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Information Taken From RateMyProfessor"> 
         <div class="progress">
             <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: {{row['profDiff']}}%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{row['profDiff']}}%
             </div>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Information Taken From RateMyProfessor">{{row['profRating']}}</td>
      <td data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Information Taken From RateMyProfessor">{{row['profWouldTakeAgain']}}</td>
    </tr>
 {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: HTML tables aren't great for responsiveness (as you've just discovered). They are also not great on small screen sizes regardless. Consider removing columns at small sizes or an alternate way of displaying the data.

Comment: This why bootstrap has `table-responsive` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `overflow: scroll` on the problematic div, so that it becomes scrollable:

```css
.container > div {
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: #fff;
}

body {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" >CRN</th>
      <th scope="col">Subject</th>
      <th scope="col">Course</th>
      <th scope="col">Credits</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Days</th>
      <th scope="col">Times</th>
      <th scope="col">Instructor</th>
      <th scope="col">Attribute</th>
      <th scope="col">Professor Difficulty</th>
      <th scope="col">Professor Rating</th>
      <th scope="col">Would Take Again</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for row in all_data %}
    <tr>
      <th><a href="https://selfserveprod.yu.edu/pls/banprd/bwckschd.p_disp_listcrse?term_in=202109&subj_in={{row['subj']}}&crse_in={{row['crse']}}&crn_in={{row['crn']}}" target="_blank" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Click to get register for this CRN on the YU Banner Site.">{{row['crn']}}</a></th>
      <td><strong>{{row['subj']}}</strong></td>
      <td >{{row['crse']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['cred']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['title']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['days']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['time']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['instr']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['Attr']}}</td>
      <td data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Information Taken From RateMyProfessor"> <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: {{row['profDiff']}}%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{row['profDiff']}}%</div>
</div>
</td>
      <td data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Information Taken From RateMyProfessor">{{row['profRating']}}</td>
      <td data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Information Taken From RateMyProfessor">{{row['profWouldTakeAgain']}}</td>
    </tr>
 {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

---

Alternatively, you can use some Javascript to check the current screen width, and then resize content appropriately using CSS's `transform: scale()`. In the example below I used jQuery for brevity, but this can sure be done using plain JS. Two things to note here:

- The content should resize as the browser window is resized;
- When using `transform: scale`, it is best to also set the `transform-origin` of the div to `top-left` so that the div does not "move around" as it is scaled.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  resizeTable();
});

$(window).on("resize", function() {
  resizeTable();
});

function resizeTable() {
  var width = $(document).width();
  
  // if width / 1500 is greater than 1, set scale to 1
  // (i.e. do not zoom in stuff if the screen is very large)
  // here 1500 is only an example, you can set the number to whatever you see fit
  scale = Math.min(width / 1500, 1);
  
  $(".container table").css("transform", `scale(${scale})`);
}
```

```css
.container > div {
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container table {
  transform-origin: left top;
}

body {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" >CRN</th>
      <th scope="col">Subject</th>
      <th scope="col">Course</th>
      <th scope="col">Credits</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Days</th>
      <th scope="col">Times</th>
      <th scope="col">Instructor</th>
      <th scope="col">Attribute</th>
      <th scope="col">Professor Difficulty</th>
      <th scope="col">Professor Rating</th>
      <th scope="col">Would Take Again</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for row in all_data %}
    <tr>
      <th><a href="https://selfserveprod.yu.edu/pls/banprd/bwckschd.p_disp_listcrse?term_in=202109&subj_in={{row['subj']}}&crse_in={{row['crse']}}&crn_in={{row['crn']}}" target="_blank" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Click to get register for this CRN on the YU Banner Site.">{{row['crn']}}</a></th>
      <td><strong>{{row['subj']}}</strong></td>
      <td >{{row['crse']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['cred']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['title']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['days']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['time']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['instr']}}</td>
      <td>{{row['Attr']}}</td>
      <td data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Information Taken From RateMyProfessor"> <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: {{row['profDiff']}}%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{row['profDiff']}}%</div>
</div>
</td>
      <td data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Information Taken From RateMyProfessor">{{row['profRating']}}</td>
      <td data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Information Taken From RateMyProfessor">{{row['profWouldTakeAgain']}}</td>
    </tr>
 {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

---

**However**, this second approach is not optimal for very small screens, e.g. mobile phones, as **text will become way too small to read**. So, such small screens should ideally be handled separately using CSS media queries.

Comment: This is a cool solution and I appreciate it! However, seems annoying to end user to see their content cut off, any other ways to handle this? Cant I down-scale/push off the rest of the div to make it fit?